# How to update background-image without verifying the cache

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a simple image slideshow for my website. Basically, it's just a Javascript function that runs every 5 seconds and updates a div element's CSS "background-image" property. It works good, however, I've noticed that it contacts the server every time that the function runs to verify the image is in the cache. This produces a 304 code from the server each time.

The images will certainly be in the cache since they are images that are already contained somewhere else on the same page. Therefore, they are already loaded into the cache when the website loads originally.

Here is a simplified sample of my code. As you can see, the image URL is just being pulled right from an `img` element already loaded on the page:

```
function update(img) {
     var slideshow = document.getElementById("slideshow");
     slideshow.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + image + '")';
}

function advance() {
     var img = document.getElementsByClassName("slidesource")[index].src;
     update(img);
     index++;
}

var index = 0;
advance();
setInterval(advance,5000);
```

Is there a way to update the CSS property without the browser having to verify that the images are in the cache?

Verifying that they exist wastes internet data (albeit only around 1.5kB per request) and will cause the slideshow to stop working if the internet is disconnected, even if the images are already in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your issue, trying your code with some img tags and a div tag.

However, I sort of could replicate if if I manually turned off cache in Chrome and turned it on again. Anyway, with the following code below, I didn't get any issues with the images trying to load again from the server.

**CSS Solution**

```
<style>
  #slideshow {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
  }

  .img1 {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/400/400")
  }

  .img2 {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/400/401")
  }

  .img3 {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/400/402")
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div id="slideshow"></div>

</body>

<script>
function update(imgclassName) {
   var slideshow = document.getElementById("slideshow");
   slideshow.classList.remove( slideshow.classList[0] );
   slideshow.classList.add(imgclassName);
}

function advance() {
  update('img'+index);
  index++;
  if (index > NUMBER_OF_IMAGES) {
    index = 1;
  }
}

var NUMBER_OF_IMAGES = 3;
var index = 1;
advance();
setInterval(advance,1000);
</script>
```